# Why is this SQLite in JavaScript not working?

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I have included SQLite and SQLite statements in my program.  I have a table named PILE and PILE table has the following columns

Word|Meaning|Frequency|C1|C2|C3|C4|C5

```
tx.executeSql(

"UPDATE PILE SET ? = COALESCE( (SELECT ? FROM PILE WHERE word = ?), 0 ) -1 WHERE word = ?", 

            [category1, category1, incorrectmanualanswer, incorrectmanualanswer] ,
 errorcode  );

alert("down "+category1+"+"+incorrectmanualanswer);
```

The above does not execute.  I do see the correct values in the following alert window

But the below executes perfectly

```
function screenONEpress(tx) 
{               
tx.executeSql(

"UPDATE PILE SET frequency = COALESCE( (SELECT frequency FROM PILE WHERE word = ?), 0 ) + 1 

WHERE word = ?", [newEword, newEword] , errorcode   );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

parameter interpolation quotes and escapes the parameters for use in sql statements, and does not insert barewords into the sql code.  So the generated sql would look something like `UPDATE PILE SET 'category1' = COALESCE( ...` which is a syntax error.